# MySQL Database Design Performance And Query

Tags: mysql, performance

[MySQL DB Design Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQqHn.jpg)

Hi
As you can see there are 2 kinda designs we've got here. Both of them are based on that there is only one row per main table or mains table row in the other relation tables. [1:1]

Design 1:
there are null-able foreign-keys of tables; items, others, seconds in mains table

Design 2:
there is foreign-key of main table in others

My Question is, which design is appropriate?  For making Select SQL query, in "Design 1" there is a need of using UNION and for "Design 2" LEFT JOIN would be the choice I assume. So, in terms of performance through large amount of data which is suitable and how should be the sql query?

UPDATED :

```
SELECT mains.id as mainId, items.id as id, mains.title as title, items.name as name
    FROM items, mains where mains.itemId=items.id
UNION
SELECT mains.id as mainId, others.id as id, mains.title as title, others.name as name
    FROM others, mains where mains.otherId=others.id  
UNION
SELECT mains.id as mainId, seconds.id as id, mains.title as title, seconds.name as name
    FROM seconds, mains where mains.secondId=seconds.id

------------------------------

SELECT  *
    FROM  mains
    LEFT JOIN  items ON mains.itemId=items.Id
    LEFT JOIN  seconds ON mains.secondId=seconds.id
    LEFT JOIN  others ON mains.otherId=others.id 

------------------------------

SELECT main.id as mainId, item.id as id, main.title as title, item.name as name
    FROM item, main where main.id=item.mainId
UNION
SELECT main.id as mainId, other.id as id, main.title as title, other.name as name
    FROM other, main where main.id=other.mainId  
UNION
SELECT main.id as mainId, second.id as id, main.title as title, second.name as name
    FROM second, main where main.id=second.mainId

-------------------------------

SELECT  *
    FROM  mains
    LEFT JOIN  items ON mains.itemId=items.Id
    LEFT JOIN  seconds ON mains.secondId=seconds.id
    LEFT JOIN  others ON mains.otherId=others.id
```

different sql query approach..! which one? performance?

Comment: show some sample data and what out put you want to fetch....

Comment: It is like you pick a journey by flight or ship or train, they've got different structure in each following tables.. now do you think you need me to provide data?

Comment: better option will be to keep one table with journey_type column which will contains either flight, train, ship or their initials.

Answer (score 0):

If each record in main table has one-to-one relationship with item, other and second tables I prefer store them all in one single table and avoid need of using JOIN or UNION.

Comment: you know, you can't have it all in one, since each table has different columns but unanimous in main relation table..

Comment: Do you mean that it is 1:1, _but_ some rows are missing in the `seconds` and `others`?  If so, you will have a mess either way, and your application code will need to sort out the rows or columns.

Comment: Ok, now I understand what you want to do. In my opinion to determine if a query is fast or not you need to know how MySQL will execute it. Can you post what EXPLAIN output?